# Trying to plot a wave from planetary degree in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a function in Excel-VBA which will take three parameters planet degree, pattern and amplitude. The function should plot a wave according to the pattern specified. if pattern is 2 then the wave will increase till 180 degree and from 180 to 360 it will decrease and comes to 0. If pattern is 3 it will divide the circle into three parts of 120 each and increase till 120 degree then decrease till 240 degree and finally increase again.

I have write the function already. It works fine with the `pattern==2`. But in case of `pattern == 3`, it become inconsistent when planetary degree changes from 359 to 0. it drops from highest amplitude to 0.

```
['''
Public Function Wave( _
   planet As Double, _
   Pattern As Integer, _
   Amp As Double) _
As Double


     If Pattern = 2 Then 'calculating square wave
        If planet <= 180 Then
           Wave = (planet * Amp) / 180
        ElseIf planet > 180 Then
           Wave = ((360 - planet) * Amp) / 180
        End If

     End If


     If Pattern = 3 Then 'calculating trine wave
         If planet <= 120 Then
            Wave = (planet * Amp) / 120
         ElseIf planet > 120 And planet <= 240 Then
            Wave = ((240 - planet) * Amp) / 120
         ElseIf planet > 240 Then
            Wave = ((planet - 240) * Amp) / 120
         End If
     End If

End Function
'''][1]

'''
If Pattern = 33 Then 'calculating trine wave using 720 insted of 360 zodiac
         If planet <= 120 Then
            Wave = (planet * Amp) / 120
         ElseIf planet > 120 And planet <= 240 Then
            Wave = ((240 - planet) * Amp) / 120
         ElseIf planet > 240 And planet <= 360 Then
            Wave = ((planet - 240) * Amp) / 120
         ElseIf planet > 360 And planet <= 480 Then
            Wave = ((480 - planet) * Amp) / 120
         ElseIf planet > 480 And planet <= 600 Then
            Wave = ((planet - 480) * Amp) / 120
         ElseIf planet > 600 Then
            Wave = ((720 - planet) * Amp) / 120
         End If
     End If
'''
```

Now if I convert the planetary degree to 720 degree instead of 360 and apply the above code it works fine. But I am unable to figure out to convert 360 cycle to 720 degree. lower chart is made using 720 degree cycle and pattern==33

Charts can be viewed [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAxEj.png)

Comment: Can you also add the Graph to understand it Better ? Screenshots will do

Comment: screenshot added at the top